# Is there a way to call lightning component from a flow

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, visual-workflow

I want to open a lightning component from a list button in case. Which opens up case in edit mode. The client dont want to embed it in VF.  is there any other way. Can flow invoke lightning component? I have searched a lot, im not getting any ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add Lightning Components in Flow screens in Spring '18, have a look to the release notes [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_lc_screens.htm).